# What is knotted in EM and GR?

Tags: general-relativity, maxwell-equations, topological-field-theory

I found this paper with beautiful illustrations: [Helicity, Topology and Kelvin Waves in reconnecting quantum knots](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.06880), and this one which seems to describe something closely analogous: [New knotted solutions of Maxwell's equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01382), and realized I need help understanding what these papers are really describing.

The illustrations appear to describe closed trajectories that loop through "tunnels" in a surface and, as a result, are knotted.  Of course they are 2D representations of something that occurs in (3+1)D, but that doesn't ease my confusion.

I think of knots as something like a knot in a string: such a knot is stable because the string can't pass through itself.  It is easy to imagine a knotted toroidal coil whose magnetic field is therefore knotted, but the magnetic field's existence would depend on the current in the coil. Abruptly turn off the current, and the field would "untie" itself almost instantly.  But it appears that the second reference above describes stable electromagnetic knots in a vacuum.

The question is: can there literally be knots in a vacuum electromagnetic field? And if so can they be stable?

Comment: Here is another two papers building on this, that seems to support the possibility: https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys1056 and https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.111.150404  However, I think one can make an argument based that such knots are not going to be stable. Earnshaw's theorem prevent the static case, and Shafranov showed that the electromagnetic version of the virial theorem leads to dispersion unless there is an external force. Still, the topological invariants would remain.

Comment: In [https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0009061] and [https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0003083] it is shown (theoretically) that stable solitons can exist in a plasma.  Of course, a plasma is not a vacuum, but this suggests that at least with the right nonlinearities (think vacuum polarization) stable knots in an electromagnetic field might be possible.  Also, "stable" would not exclude periodic structures.

Comment: There is a funny literature from the ball lightening community trying to make stable plasma solitons or knots with no external confinement, but the Shafranov result seems to block this possibility fairly profoundly.